# R - how can I use neural networks for a binary dependent variable in R?

Tags: r, neural-networks

I have a dataset from a bank with demographic data and one variable telling if the customer is a good customer or not (binary variable). I would like to do prediction on if the customer is good or not based on this demographic data.

I managed to do it with a logistic regression, but would like now to compare the result (classification rate) with neural networks.

I found 2 functions from different packages doing that:

- `nnet()`
- `neuralnet()`

But those functions seem to be conceived for numerical dependent variables.

Is there a possibility to use these functions for a categorical numerical variable (by estimating a posteriori probabilities for instance) or is there another function doing that?

Comment: Welcome to crossvalidated. I'm not sure whether this question is better suited for cross-validated or stackoverflow (where programming questions are discussed). IMHO it is more a programming than a statistics question , so I'll flag it for moderator attention, and the moderators can decide whether it should stay here or be moved to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nnet::multinom` does multinomial (or logistic) regression via an ANN without hidden layer. Internally, it uses `nnet::nnet`. So if you look into `multinom`'s code, you should be able to derive a `nnet` with hidden layer, but otherwise similar to multinom (i.e. predicting probabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try but I am not experienced at all with programing R functions so not sure I will manage to do this. So there is no existing function doing this?

Comment: Ok it wasn't that complicated finally. I just modified the 'size' arguments (adding hidden layers) and the response totally makes sense. So I guess I did right :)
Thanks!